# A database in which the users can create data types

Tags: sql, database, nosql

I have a really old application using an SQL database that I need to update. I would like to take also the opportunity to improve the database structure and I would appreciate some advice.

The basic problem is that an important part of the database must be user configurable without touching the code. To be more concrete, the DB stores products and these products have different specs (i.e. columns) depending on the type. The app must be able to search for any of the columns. There are only a few types (~20) but the administrator must be able to create a new one without touching the code.
The data that needs to be stored for each product are either strings or floats, and never more than 7 of each type.

Instead of creating an interface to create and delete tables, the following "solution" was implemented.
- In the Products Table, there is one column for the id; one column for the ProducTypeID; 7 string columns and 7 float columns
- In a ProducType column, there is one column for the ProducTypeID, and 14 string columns indicating the names of the 7 string columns and 7 float columns for each product type. If a product does not need so many columns, the column name is NULL

This works but due to the extra indirection is extremely annoying to maintain the client code.

The question is: Should I stay with an SQL DB and add a way to create/delete tables or should I use a noSQL DB? Which are the pros and cons in each case?

Comment: Not all NoSQL databases are schemaless.

Comment: @Philipp: you are off course right. Thanks for the clarification.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Keep in mind that in SQL databases, adding and removing columns on a large table can be a very expensive operation which can take minutes or even hours. Doing it on-the-fly is a really bad idea. Adding a bunch of "multi-purpose" columns to a table is not much better. It's hard to query and you have a limit on how many properties a product can have.

The usual by-the-book solution when each product has 0-n dynamic properties is to create a second table `ProductID(primary key) | PropertyName(primary key) | PropertyValue`. This allows each product to have any number of properties. You can easily `JOIN` it with the main products table to get all products with their properties.

When you are open to switching database technologies, you could also use a document-oriented NoSQL database which doesn't use a fixed schema like MongoDB or CouchDB. In such databases, each document in a collection can have a different set of fields. But before you decide to make this step, evaluate how such a database would affect other parts of your application. Listing *everything* that *could* be positively or negatively affected without knowing your whole application in and out would be too broad of a question.

Comment: In this "by-the-book" solution, how do you deal with multiple data types. Do I need to create one table for FloatProperties and one for StringProperties?

Comment: @Hernan That would be one option. Another option would be to create one table with two property-columns with different types.